# How to update many to many relationships using SQLAlchemy and FastAPI?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

**models.py**

```
class Role(Base):
    __tablename__='role'
    role_id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    role_name = Column(String(20),nullable=False)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__='user'
    user_id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String(20),nullable=False)

class UserRoles(Base):
    __tablename__="user_roles"
    user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("User.user_id"),primary_key=True)
    role_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("Role.role_id"),primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Integer,nullable=True)
    user = relationship("User")
    role = relationship("role")
```

Data inside table "user_roles"

| user_id | role_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

How can i write an API to update the user_roles table when request object to the API is {"user_id":1,"roles":[1,3]}. How can i achieve this using sqlalchemy in FastAPI?

Answer (score 1):

First you should select `UserRoles` to update:

```
results = await session.execute(
    select(UserRoles).where(UserRoles.id == user_id)
)  # where user_id = 1
user_roles = results.scalars().all()[0]
```

There might be an easier way to get one role, you should take a look at [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/)

Then select all `Roles` you want to append to ManyToMany field:

```
roles = await session.execute(select(Role).where(Role.role_id.in_(roles)))  # Where roles = [1, 3]
```

Then append them just like to list:

```
for role in roles.scalars().all():
    user_roles.role.append(role)
```

And commit session:

```
await session.commit()
```

Comment: My question is for suppose if user_id=1 has role = [1,2] and if i get a update request to the same user, where i get the payload as {user_id:1,roles:[3]} now orm has to automaticaaly remove records of 1,2 and add role=3 record.

Comment: Try this. Clear roles: user_roles.role = []. And then append roles you got at payload